# Add data to custom table in computing services in windows azure

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, azure, windows-phone-8

I developing a windows  phone app which involves storing data on azure through mobile services.
With the sample given on : 
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-phone-get-started-data/

I have been able to successfully create the tables etc.
But,
I have deleted the todoitem table from azure and instead have a table named 'meeting' with columns 'name' and 'calledby' . Could you please tell the modified code to use in my app so that data is stored in the meeting table under the aforementioned tables? I am a starter and having trouble understanding the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to have column called Id (identity) in your meeting table.

Next modify your ToDo class to reflect the table you got

```
public class Meeting
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "calledby")]
    public bool Calledby{ get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to change MobileService related instances to connect to the right table

```
private MobileServiceCollection<Meeting, Meeting> meetings;

private IMobileServiceTable<Meeting> meetingsTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<Meetings>();
```

And after that you can download data from the database into your app

```
meetings = await meetingsTable.ToCollectionAsync();
```

Hope this gets you started!